# CSS transforms on hover overrides jQuery onclick addclass transform

Tags: jquery, css, html, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am trying to get used to transforms here is what I tried to do:

```
<a id="iTryHtml5" href="IWUVUSWAGOVERFLOW">
    <img src="http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/325/1/2/princess_kenny_by_nothguy-d6v47fq.jpg"/>
</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("a#iTryHtml5").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass("rotated")) {
        $(this).removeClass("rotated");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("rotated");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
a.rotated{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

a#iTryHtml5 {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
}

a#iTryHtml5:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

The desired effect I am trying to achieve is `on:hover` scale the item to 1.1. But on click `rotateY` it 180deg maintaining 1.1 `scale`. But when **I click on the item it wont rotate until I move the mouse outside the items area**. I even tried adding `:hover` to the `.rotated` class. Does any one know how I can combine the two effects?

I am currently testing on Chrome thats why only the webkit prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was basically just a [specificity issue](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). Make the selector more specific.

- `a.rotated` has a specificity value of `11`. (type + class)
- `a#iTryHtml5:hover` has a specificity of `111`. (type + id + pseudo class)
- `a#iTryHtml5.rotated` also has a specificity of `111`. (type + id + class)

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9yYwL/)

```
a#iTryHtml5.rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

When you were hovering over the element, the selector `a#iTryHtml5:hover` was overwriting the styling from `a.rotated`. You were therefore not seeing the element rotate until after the more specific selector was removed from the equation.

You should also add in the following selector to prevent another specificity issue when hovering over the rotated element. In other words, this just allows you to increase the scale of the element when hovering over the rotated version.

```
a#iTryHtml5.rotated:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotateY(180deg);
}
```